# Generating dynamic number of elements in a page with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, templates, grid

Ive got an `form-group` with some `text-input`s. Users are free to fill arbitrary number of fields.

After filling the form, its passed to a php processor which is in charge of creating & populating the template.

I'm having problem creating a proper grid/template for positioning different number of elements in page, which arises because of variety of filled elements by users.

Following is the result of a try:

```
<p class="header">
    <b>Header which the user has token</b>
</p>
<br />
<!-- Number of a tags is based on number of filled fields-->
<a href="#field1"><p>Theme from the user</p></a>
<a href="#field2"><p>Theme from the user</p></a>
<a href="#field3"><p>Theme from the user</p></a>
<br />
<a name="field1">
    <h2>Text from the user who filled up the textinput</h2>
</a>
<br />
<a name="field2">
    <h2>Text from the user who filled up the textinput</h2>
</a>
<br />
<a name="field3">
    <h2>Text from the user who filled up the textinput</h2>
</a>
```

Does anyone has similar experience? I'd appreciate any creative idea.

Comment: Do you have any PHP code to show us? We can help you, but we won't do your work for you.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure to review [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I have the Template and the Form to send the Textinput. But not the php file which is "adding" the text to my template. I have really no idea how i can do that.

Comment: When you want to achieve something in a programming language, you should first learn this language. When you know at least the basics, you will see, that you request is a very simple task.